# Cross-platform video conversion tool + Python ( Gstreamer ? )

Tags: python, macos, video, gstreamer

I'm looking for a tool to do the following:

1. Convert video/audio from multiple formats to WebM format.
2. Needs to be command-line or *Python*-binded.
3. Cross-platform.
4. **No royalty licenses** - Thus, all *FFMpeg*-based tools are out - [See this for an explanation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html).

The best framework I've found so far is **GStreamer**, But I'm not sure if it's cross-platform or if *gst-python* is cross-platform. I've installed *GStreamer* on my mac using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), but it's missing some elements (i.e. *alsasink*), and I don't think I can compile *gst-python* for Mac. They require *pygtk*. Everything there is *linux*-based (-only!) :(

Know anything else that might do the trick? Or how can I fix *Gstreamer* + *gst-python* to work properly on *mac/win/linux* altogether?

Comment: Just so you know, I did get video and audio playback going with GStreamer on a Mac using MacPorts (http://www.macports.org/). You may want to give them a try for the Mac.

Comment: Like I said, I've already installed GStreamer on my Mac using homebrew, which is an updated/new MacPorts. I can't get gst-python installed properly and can't find proper documentation on how to convert video using Gstreamer.

Comment: I don't understand why FFmpeg's license is a dealbreaker for you.  The core is under LGPL, and WebM doesn't require any of its GPL components.  WRT MPEG-LA royalties: there are companies that have managed to get MPEG-LA to bless their FFmpeg-based products, and there are companies using non-FFmpeg libraries which have gotten legal pressure.

Comment: If I ever want to convert *from* patent-backed formats (i.e. H.264-based formats) to WebM, that would be a problem/risk.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for format conversion. FFMPEG v.0.6 adds support for VP8 (WebM)

Comment: This is no good. Like I said - FFmpeg has problems with license and royalties. You can check the link above for explanation. Thanks anyways...

Comment: I don't understand the problem with FFMPEG too. LGPL doesn't satisfy your needs? or you need GPL'ed parts of FFMPEG? if FFMPEG doesn't have them under LGPL so there's little chance you'll find this functionality under more relaxed license

Comment: No, FFmpeg has unclarified patent issues. It (might) use algorithmes that are patent-backed. Thus, the companies behind the patents may require royalties in the future. Just read the bottom of the page in the link. It's there.

Comment: almost every encoder/decoder uses them, I think WebM too. if you need to convert from/to popular formats so I don't believe you can avoid usage of patented algorithms

Comment: You are wrong about this. For example, you can view GStreamer's "good" plugins. These one don't have any patent-risks.

Comment: how can you be sure until some corp sued you? especially in such patent-crowded place as multimedia codecs

Comment: (Some projects have strict licensing requirements.)